# AngularJs js Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] error after adding routing

Tags: angularjs

I'm newer to AngularJs. First i was added one samplecontroller and run that it was working fine. Next i added the routing in my sample application it's not working . I dont know whether this is js dependency issue or somewhat.

[image: My Html Code]

[image: Javascript File]

Comment: Don't use the minified version of angular in development. And post the complete stack trace. And post your code as text, not as images. It's much harder for us to copy and paste your code to fix it in the answers when posted as image.

Comment: Okay @JBNizet I'll try and revert back it to u ... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have added the script for angular-route, but you haven't loaded the `ngRoute` module in your app:

```
angular.module('demoApplication', ['ngRoute']);
```

This is well described in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: Thanks @JB it's working after adding this... Actually i saw 60-ish minutes video through youtube they mentioned like that only ... I did't see this document.. anyway thanks

Comment: Always rely on the official, reference documentation. Youtube is great for lolcats videos.